# SAT reading questions

Tags: exam-questions

I need help on question 17 and 18 on Section 4 page 17. Scroll down on the following website to find section 4.

Here's the website to find the passage and questions.

https://satonlinecourse.collegeboard.org/SR/digital_assets/assessment/pdf/F4D31AB0-66B4-CE32-00F7-F5405701F413-F.pdf

Passage 1 suggests that the Fermi Paradox depends 
most directly on which assumption?

Question 17. I think none of the answers are valid. Correct answer is C.
I thought the passage says that extraterrestrial technology develops faster or slower than the rate of human... they develop not on the pace of human tech.

Q18. I have no idea. Correct Answer is E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q17. The correct answer is indeed C. The passage talks about how civilizations that started at different times would interact, but does not consider that science and technology can improve faster or slower depending on who or what is doing the development (among other factors).

The assumption is that, a civilization which started later than we did would never be able to overtake us, and also that we could never catch up to a civilization more advanced than we are, because all civilizations develop science and technology at roughly the same rate. In reality, we should not assume that all civilizations advance at the same rate. Lines 23 and 24 setup the concept of the "rate of human technology", while lines 26 to 35 are built on this assumption.

Q18. To answer this question, you have to think from the perspective of the author of Passage 2. The author of Passage 2 raises several points, raised by other scientists, that run counter to the claim of "consensus" in Passage 1. It is an oversimplification to say that there is a consensus when in fact there are multiple strong views that are against the possibility that we would discover intelligent extraterrestrial life (or that they would discover us). To say that there is a consensus is to say that since there are no sufficiently strong opinions against X, then the community approves X.  But in reality, there isn't a consensus, as there are at least 3 (Fermi, Drake, Zuckerman, and so on) strong, defensible opinions in the community.

Comment: can u also help with question 10 on section 8? I think C. is a possibility but D. is the answer. The author mentions a performance specialist so I think C.

Comment: http://www.collegeboard.com/prod_downloads/sat/satguide/SAT_full_0405.pdf    Can u help me with question one on section 7? I think E. is also a possibility but the correct answer is D.

Comment: i also need help on question 10. I think C but the correct is A.

Comment: http://www.collegeboard.com/prod_downloads/sat/satguide/SAT_Full.pdf  I have no idea for section 4 number 26.

Comment: and i need further explanation for number 31 section 4.

Comment: http://www.collegeboard.com/prod_downloads/sat/html/may2002/sat_may02.pdf  i have no idea for question 33 and 34 section 1. correct anwser is D for q33 and A for q34. for this question

Comment: @Ben: As much as I would like to answer all these questions, I don't have the time to do so. You would probably be better off posting these as separate questions, so you can get insights from others too.